# Android service keeps running indefinitely

Tags: android, service

I'm trying to create a service in android which i want to keep running in background indefinitely. So I tried to create one like :

```
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    Toast.makeText(this, mssg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags,int startid) {
    Toast.makeText(this, mssg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Log.d("Start:", "Service running");

           // my code here

    return START_STICKY;
}
```

But when I run this code, the toast messages and logs are only shown once , so does it mean service runs only first time. If it is running again n again which API of it is being called repeatedly ?

Thanks,
shadow.

Answer (score 1):

Running a Service indefinitely and running the same piece of code again and again are two very different things. The piece of code you provided will allow the service to be running the background as long as the Android system doesn't decide to stop it.

Not sure what functionality you are looking to implement, but i suggest you read up on what exactly a Service is used for and what your requirements are.

Comment: Oh, is it like threads where I put an infinite-while loop to continuously looking for event to happen ?

Comment: No it's not like an *infinite-loop*. `Services` are components which are dedicated to do a certain tasks. They do these tasks without requiring a UI context and do not have a time restriction on completing tasks. It is like a task that will run in the background and notify you when it is done. It can do the task again if you ask it to do it again, it won't magically execute itself again. I suggest you read up more on it before you proceed with implementation -> http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html

Answer (score 0):

i suggest you change `return START_STICKY;` 
with `return START_NOT_STICKY;`

as details given in documentation  [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#START_NOT_STICKY).